# How can I make existing views in database into files in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have made a database in PostgreSQL 9.3 and made some views in the database.
I was wondering if there is any way to get those views out of database as separate `.sql` files?

Comment: See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html

Comment: -1 Check [`copy`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) and [`\copy`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the SQL statement behind the view, you can get that using `pg_get_viewdef()`

```
select pg_get_viewdef('your_view_name');
```

More details in the manual:
 http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE

Answer (score 0):

Managed to deal with this by exporting whole database using pg_dump and then making new separate .sql files

Comment: Which is exactly what `pg_get_viewdef` will also give you